# Get GrammaticalRelation of root node

Tags: parsing, stanford-nlp

I'm attempting to parse Medical research reports, using the Stanford NLP.  I can get the GrammaticalRelation of all the nodes except the first or root node. How do I get this valus.

I have written a java program which parses reports by getting the dependency graph and can get the child pairs of all the nodes except the root node.

```
    public void DocAnnotationParse(String Input_text) {
    Annotation document = new Annotation(Input_text);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    //props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse");
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,parse");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    int sentNum = 0;
    Map<String, Map<String, Map<String,IndexedWord>>> sentMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // A map contains maps of each sentence
    for (CoreMap sentence : document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
        SemanticGraph dependencyParse = sentence.get(SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.BasicDependenciesAnnotation.class);
        IndexedWord firstVertex = dependencyParse.getFirstRoot();
        Map<String, Map<String,IndexedWord>> outterMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        RecursiveChild(outterMap, dependencyParse, firstVertex, 0);
        sentMap.put(Integer.toString(++sentNum), outterMap);
        logger.debug("outtermap: "+outterMap);
    }
    logger.debug("all sentMaps: "+sentMap);
    PrettyPrintBySentence(sentMap);
}


public void RecursiveChild(Map<String, Map<String, IndexedWord>> outterMap,
        SemanticGraph dependencyParse, 
        IndexedWord vertex, int hierLevel) {

    Map<String, IndexedWord> pairMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    pairMap.put("Root", vertex);
    List<IndexedWord>indxwdsL = dependencyParse.getChildList(vertex);
    List<Pair<GrammaticalRelation,IndexedWord>>childPairs = dependencyParse.childPairs(vertex);
    List<IndexedWord> nxtLevalAL = new ArrayList<>();
    if(!indxwdsL.isEmpty()) {
        ++hierLevel;    
        for(Pair<GrammaticalRelation, IndexedWord> aPair : childPairs) { //at level hierLevel x
            logger.debug(aPair);
            String grammRel = aPair.first.toString(); //Gramatic Relation
            IndexedWord indxwd = aPair.second;
            pairMap.put(grammRel, indxwd);
            List<Pair<GrammaticalRelation,IndexedWord>>childPairs2 = dependencyParse.childPairs(indxwd);
            if(!childPairs2.isEmpty()) {
                nxtLevalAL.add(indxwd);
            }
        }
    }
    String level = Integer.toString(hierLevel);     
    outterMap.put(level, pairMap);
    //Go to each lower level
    for(IndexedWord nxtIwd : nxtLevalAL) {
        RecursiveChild(outterMap, dependencyParse, nxtIwd, hierLevel);
    }
}
```

The childPair for the root vertex does not contain a Grammatical Relation, which I want.  Looking at the dependency graph there is no value but just the string root. How do I get the Grammatical Relation for that node. For example the simple sentence "I love French fries." gives the graph:

```
-> love/VBP (root)
  -> I/PRP (nsubj)
  -> fries/NNS (dobj)
    -> French/JJ (amod)
  -> ./. (punct)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm not a linguistics person, but my understanding is that there is simply a `ROOT` node outside of the `SemanticGraph`, and a `root` edge points from the root to a word(s) in the sentence.

So in your example the `ROOT` node is attached to the word `love` with the `root` relation.

If you look at the code of SemanticGraph it explicitly states:

```
* The root is not at present represented as a vertex in the graph.
* At present you need to get a root/roots
* from the separate roots variable and to know about it.
```

You can access the list of roots (I guess there can hypothetically be more than one?) with the `getRoots()` method.  But I think all that means is that a `root` edge flows from the `ROOT` node into those words.

If you want an actual Java object to represent that rather than a String, there is `edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalRelation.ROOT` which represents this relationship between the "faked ROOT node" and the roots.

```
  /**
   *  The "root" grammatical relation between a faked "ROOT" node, and the root of the sentence.
   */
  public static final GrammaticalRelation ROOT =
    new GrammaticalRelation(Language.Any, "root", "root", null);
```